# Find x knowing AO=OB=R

Tags: geometry

[image]

---

Find $x$ knowing that $OB=OA=R$

I know the answer is  $\frac{R^2+r^2}{Rr}$

This question is driving me crazy.

Comment: The answer you give cannot be correct since it has the wrong dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw the triangle with vertices OBX where X is the centre of the circle of radius $x$. Drop a perpendicular from X onto OB.

Note that $|OX|=R-x$ and $|BX|=r+x$. The perpendicular divides $OB$ into lengths $x$ and $R-x$.

Applying Pythagoras then gives

$$(R-x)^2-x^2=(r+x)^2-(R-x)^2$$

Expanding and solving for $x$ gives 
$$x=\frac{2R^2-r^2}{2r+4R}$$